# fs-extra readFile is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, fs, fs-extra

I'm trying to generate pdf with puppeteer and I'm having an issue when I need to bring the handlebars file along.

In the tutorial the guy was using fs-extra npm package so that is the one I installed,

```
const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8')
```

But apprently it's not a function, I went to the npm doc and I haven't found anything similar,
is it only used for moving/deleting/copying/... files and dirs now ?
I'm a bit lost, do I need to change to another npm package ? or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote this question too early, just read that it's included in Node.js. It should have merged together with the fs-extra package as specified in the doc but it didn't somehow...

Anyway using the classic node `fs` works for me.